# Paginated list of results using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple SQL Server DB containing data for Users and Communities. Any user can be member of any number of communities, so I have 3 tables: `Users`, `Communities` and `Map`, and corresponding POCO C# classes.
I use EntityFramework to get the dictionary of all communities and their memebers:

```
public Dictionary<Community, List<User>> GetData()
{
    var communitiesAndUsers =
        from community in DbContext.Communities
        from map in DbContext.CommunityUserMap.Where(c => c.Community == community )
        select new { Community = community, User = map.User };


    var result = new Dictionary<Community, List<User>>();
    foreach (var communityGroup in communitiesAndUsers.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.Community.Id))
    {
        var community = communityGroup.First().Community;
        var users = communityGroup.Select(g => g.User).ToList();
        result.Add(community, users);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now I need to support pagination in this method:

```
public Dictionary<Community, List<User>> GetData(int page, int communitiesPerPage)
```

And I have a requirement to do it using 1 SQL query. How do I need to modify my method to support that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Skip` and `Take` to implement the paging. You will also need to define sort criteria (`Orderby`) to get consistent results.

```
var pagedCommunityGroups = communitiesAndUsers
    .GroupBy(cau => cau.Community.Id)
    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
    .Skip(page * communitiesPerPage) // assume first page has number 0
    .Take(communitiesPerPage)
    .ToList();                       // execute query
```

Because `communitiesAndUsers` has not been enumerated before you apply `Skip` and `Take`, this will result in a single SQL query (query will be executed on `ToList`).

Comment: But this will produce a list of pairs <community-user>, with the length of `communitiesPerPage`. So the `result` dictionary will possibly contain less than `communitiesPerPage` records, because mapping can contain duplicate communityIds. I need the `result` dictionary to contain exactly `communitiesPerPage` keys.

Comment: Right, I just changed the query to apply the `GroupBy` before the `Skip` and `Take`, this should yield the expected result.